# Error during build and reload in R

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

I am roxygenizing a package I am making in R.

The script is

```
#' HandyTools
#'
#' Check if required packages are installed or not and installs them if not
#' @param packageList - a list containing the required package names
#'
#' @examples
#' checkPackagesLibrary(c("lme4","epitools","roxygen2"))
#'
#' @export
library(devtools)
checkPackagesLibrary <- function(packagesList){
  new.packages <- packagesList[!(packagesList %in% installed.packages(lib.loc="/data/legacy/user/R_Packages")[,"Package"])]
  if(length(new.packages))
    install.packages(new.packages, lib = "/data/legacy/user/R_Packages")
  else
    print("Required packages are already installed")
}
```

While build and reload in RStudio, the error is:

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))

Updating HandyTools documentation
Loading HandyTools
Error: Missing name at code.R:14
In addition: Warning message:
In setup_ns_exports(pkg, export_all) :
  Objects listed as exports, but not present in namespace: c
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Error is at line 14, which is

```
library(devtools)
```

If I comment this line, the error disappears.

Answer (score 3):

Rookie error: you are not supposed to have `library()...` calls in scripts in your packages.

Use `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` instead, preferably via `Imports:` and `importFrom()` statements.

Comment: For rookies: rather than use library(package), in packages it is considered better to fully specify every use of a package with the :: such as data.table::uniqueN

Comment: @PeterVermont what is standard practice when we call upon functions from another package *many* times. It really dirties up the code to write `dplyr::` a hundred times. I specify the packages it requires with `Imports:`. It seems SOP to still include `package::` at the beginning, but I really don't want to do that.